# Change the font used by all sectioning commands to Helvetica

Tags: fonts, sectsty, helvetica

I found this line in a template.

```
\allsectionsfont{\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}} % Change the font of all section commands (Helvetica)
```

This not working with my chars in Polish language. How change this to use 'ą' 'ś' 'ę' etc.

link template: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wenneker-article

Comment: `\allsectionsfont{\usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n}}` should do the trick. Also, you can load `newpxtext`: you'll have a clone of helvetica with real small caps.

Comment: @Bernard can You write example?

Answer (score 3):

You should do

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{helvet}
```

and then

```
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
```

(change the scale factor to suit). There should be a single choice for the sans serif font in a document.

I assume you're doing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, as Polish needs it.

---

The scale value 0.8 is just a guess; my opinion is that the standard scaling factor 0.95 is too big. Unless you need to mix sans serif and serif text on the same line, a value is as good as another (so personal preference gets in the choice).

You might also consider `tgheros` instead of `helvet`; it offers a `scale` option (not `scaled` like `helvet`)

```
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{tgheros}
```

but also `matchlowercase` or `matchuppercase`:

```
\usepackage[matchlowercase]{tgheros}

\usepackage[matchuppercase]{tgheros}
```

which shouldn't need explanation.

Comment: how using other font for example TeX Gyre? this {helvet} is this same font \usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n} ? or not?

Comment: @MarkoLustro You can also do `\usepackage{scale=0.8]{tgheros}`, yes.

Comment: Could you maybe add a brief explanation as to why you recommend applying a scaling factor of 0.8 while loading the `helvet` package? (If the main text font is Computer Roman, a scaling factor of 0.84 would equalize the x-heights of Computer Modern and Helvetica. )

Comment: @Mico You're right, I added the explanation.